# Rescinding job offer acceptance for a different offer

Tags: job-offer

I was laid off back in September and started to apply for new positions right away.  I submitted my resume to every opportunity I seemed qualified for and it took a while to get any bites.

I was in the interview process with one company for about 3 weeks before they offered me the job.  They presented the job as primarily remote with occasional in office days, which was good with me since the commute was almost 2 hours from my house. I didn’t think much of an occasional long commute day.  However when they presented the job offer, they asked for way more in-office time than previously discussed.  It kind of tainted the job offer for me.  I spoke with the hiring manager and expressed my concerns and he stated verbally that in the beginning I would need to be in office more and could eventually be more remote, however they were concerned with me managing a team remotely.  I expressed that I understood the need for in office time during training and tried to reassure him that I’d be able to manage the staff remotely and I accepted the job.

Part of me was still feeling iffy about the whole situation and continued interviewing with one other company I really meshed with. All of my interviews with this second company went amazing and I really feel like they would be a great culture for me to be apart of.  They offered me the job yesterday and only require 1 day a week in office and the commute is shorter.  They also offered $10k more in base salary.

I’ve weighed the pros and cons between the two (culture fit, career impact, commute, salary) and I really feel like I will enjoy my time at company 2 better.  How would be the best way to rescind my acceptance with the first company?

Answer (score 12):

> How would be the best way to rescind my acceptance with the first
> company?

Call as soon as possible.

Tell them you have changed your mind and won't be accepting the job offer after all.

Comment: Yeah, there is no need for explanation at this point.

Comment: If the second company is a straight shooter with their offer, then there's just no good reason to go with the first at this point. If you have training details and expectation for in-office hours during training, it would've been in the contract, not a "oh, do this for now and we'll let you remote more later". It'll never happen.

Answer (score 7):

> How would be the best way to rescind my acceptance with the first company?

There is no good way of doing this. It happens, it's not the end of the world, but it's going to ruffle some feathers no matter what you do.

Just call them and tell them in person. You can throw in something like "after some reflection I have realized that the required in-office time and the associated commute wouldn't be long term sustainable" (if you actually feel that way). This will help a little but not much.

Answer (score 2):

"Unfortunately, my circumstances have changed and I am no longer able to proceed with this opportunity"

It happens, some companies will be sour about it, most will accept that it's a reality.

You definitely want to contact them ASAP, so they can get in touch with the other candidates who didn't get the position.

Answer (score 2):

You've received an alternative offer for fewer site days, nearer to commute, and a much clearer meeting of minds from the outset. To boot, it pays $10k more!

Just tell them the hard facts - though obviously do not crow about it, instead express regret that you've now received an alternative offer that you cannot refuse.

Perhaps hold back the salary point unless directly asked, or unless they express a desire for further negotiation (in which case it can be used to emphasise the futility of further negotiation).

And make sure your alternative offer is secure before doing anything.

Comment: If you do end up mentioning the salary (whether directly or when asked), you'll need to have a response ready in case they raise their offer